# azcopy list function gives a different count (almost double) of objects than Storage Explorer

Tags: azure, azcopy

I am uploading files with AZCOPY (one by one as and when they are provided) to Azure Datalakes gen 2 and keep a track with Storage explorer and individual log of each file.

There have been 6253 file uploads and Storage explorer shows the same along with number of logs for each file upload

But when i use AZCOPY LIST  it gives me 11254.
Making it difficult to script and automate.

Is there a logical explanation for this?

There is no access issue, in fact the same AZCOPY is working on copying the files
I have tried to redownload if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug, scheduled for fixing in our next release: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/692